# Converting QVariant to a QStringList

Tags: qt, qvariant, qstringlist

I have stored `QStringList` in a `QVariant` variable while calling `setData` function. Now I'd like to restore this data from `QVariant` variable. How to do it?

Edit:
I tried convert but I don't seem to understand how it works.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`QVariant` has a [`toStringList()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvariant.html#toStringList) method.